# Hyperbolic optimization problem with linear constraints

Tags: probability, matrices, optimization

I'm looking for some insight into the following optimization problem:

$\mathrm{argmin}_p \,\,\Sigma_i \frac{1}{z_i}$

$z = \mathbf{A}p,\,\,\Sigma_i p_i = 1,\,\,0\le p_i \le 1, \mathbf{A}_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$

In other words, p is a probability vector and A is a binary feature matrix.

At the moment I'm using numerical optimization but I feel like there might be a closed form solution, or that it may at least fall under some existing class of problems.